# Send message on Instagram

Tags: html, excel, vba, instagram

I am trying to create a VBA macro code, so that the Message passed in the code can send of the profile defined in the code, to every user in our profile.I am trying doing these, by first searching the profile on Instagram and them clicking on message option and them sending the message. But i am not able to send the message to the profile.

The HTML code of text area is

```html
<div class="Igw0E IwRSH eGOV_ vwCYk ItkAi"> 
    <textarea class="" style="height: 19px;" placeholder="Message..."> </textarea> 
</div>

<hr>
```

```
Sub MessageGalGadot()
Url$ = "https://www.instagram.com/XYZ/"
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, post As Object
Dim WebUrl As String
Dim i As Integer

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate Url
    While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    While post Is Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:001")
        Set post = .Document.querySelector(".fAR91.sqdOP.L3NKy._4pI4F._8A5w5 ")
        If Not post Is Nothing Then
            post.Click
            Set msg = .Document.querySelector(".Igw0E.IwRSH.eGOV_.vwCYk.ItkAi ")
            msg.Click
            ie.Document.getElementsByName(".Igw0E.IwRSH.eGOV_.vwCYk.ItkAi").Value = "123"
        Else:
            Debug.Print "trying again"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Wend

End With
Stop
ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403190/send-message-on-instagram-profile

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because user asked same question already, see stackoverflow.com/questions/62403190/…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send Message on Instagram profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403190/send-message-on-instagram-profile)